# Printing from Python constructor using variables generated from a for loop

Tags: python, constructor

I wrote a little program to take inputs for 3 names and their respective test results and then output them in a table using the Python constructor `__init__` as below:

```
class StudentMarks:
    def __init__(self,studentName,testMark):
        self.studentName = studentName
        self.testMark = testMark

    def printInputs(self):      # Tried to just get two bits of info input each time
        print(self.studentName + "'s test score was: " + self.testMark)


student1 = input("Student name: ")
test1 = int(input("Test Score: "))
student1 = StudentMarks(student1,test1)
student2 = input("Student name: ")
test2 = int(input("Test Score: "))
student2 = StudentMarks(student2,test2)
student3 = input("Student name: ")
test3 = int(input("Test Score: "))
student3 = StudentMarks(student3,test3)


print()
print("%-10s %-5s" %("NAME","SCORE"))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(student1.studentName,student1.testMark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(student2.studentName,student2.testMark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(student3.studentName,student3.testMark))
```

This wasn't very elegant so I tried to use a for loop to get the inputs but when I try to print the results either I get the memory location (when I append a list with the results) or the variable says that it is unassigned.

Can anyone help me find where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
class StudentMarks:
    def __init__(self,studentName,testMark):
        self.studentName = studentName
        self.testMark = testMark


resultsList = []
counter = 0
for count in range(0, 3):
    counter +=1
    nameInput = str(input("Student Name: "))
    testInput = int(input("Test Score: "))
    student = str("student" + str(counter))
    resultsList.append(student)


print(resultsList)    #This shows that the variables I try to usre are in the list correctly

print()
print("%-10s %-5s" %("NAME","SCORE"))
# All these come up as not defined...
print("%-10s %-5d" %(student1.studentName,student1.testMark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(student2.studentName,student2.testMark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(student3.studentName,student3.testMark))

print()
# All of these give me AttributeErrors...
print("%-10s %-5s" %("NAME","SCORE"))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(resultsList[0].studentName,resultsList[0].testMark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(resultsList[1].studentName,resultsList[1].testMark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(resultsList[2].studentName,resultsList[2].testMark))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually initialising a student in your loop. `student` is equal to a string `str("student" + str(counter))`

I think your original approach was good, letting the student class take care of the formatted printing. Let's just make it a bit more pythonic:

```py
class StudentMarks:
    def __init__(self, student_name, test_mark):
        self.student_name = student_name
        self.test_mark = test_mark

    def print_result(self):      # Tried to just get two bits of info input each time
        print(f"{self.student_name}'s test score was: {self.test_mark}")

    def print_result_formatted(self):
        print(f"{self.student_name:10s} {self.test_mark:5d}")
```

Next, actually create objects in the for loop:

```
results_list = []
for count in range(0, 3):
    name_input = str(input("Student Name: "))
    test_input = int(input("Test Score: "))
    results_list.append(
        StudentMarks(name_input, test_input)
    )
```

And then, `results_list` will have `StudentMarks` objects, so you can print them like this:

```
print("%-10s %-5s" %("NAME","SCORE"))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(results_list[0].student_name, results_list[0].test_mark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(results_list[1].student_name, results_list[1].test_mark))
print("%-10s %-5d" %(results_list[2].student_name, results_list[2].test_mark))
```

Or like this:

```
for result in results_list:
    result.print_result_formatted()
```

Comment: Ahhh! I see! Thanks so much for that! I've been trying to solve this for days! I'm just getting started with OOP.